# Zephyr Qspi flash mount file system

Tags: zephyr-rtos

I am trying to initialize a file system on a qspi nor flash chip w25q128jvpio using zephyr os running on a stm32h753. I have already verified the hardware works and I can read and write to the flash using some bare metal applications. Now I am trying to configure it for zephyr. I am compiling against the `zephyr/sample/subsys/fs/littlefs` example and am having trouble getting the file system to mount. I assume the problem is in my device tree setup.

Bellow is my device tree overlay for the quadspi device. I also removed any mentions of "storage" or "storage_partition" from my flash0 device in my main device tree.

```
&quadspi {
    pinctrl-0 = <&quadspi_clk_pb2 &quadspi_bk2_ncs_pc11
             &quadspi_bk2_io0_pe7 &quadspi_bk2_io1_pe8
             &quadspi_bk2_io2_pe9 &quadspi_bk2_io3_pe10>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";

    flash-id = <2>;
    status = "okay";

    w25q128jvpio: qspi-nor-flash@0 {
        compatible = "st,stm32-qspi-nor";
        label = "W25Q128JVPIO";
        reg = <0>;
        qspi-max-frequency = <100000000>;
        size = <DT_SIZE_M(16*8)>;
        spi-bus-width = <4>;
        status = "okay";

        partitions {
               compatible = "fixed-partitions";
               #address-cells = <1>;
               #size-cells = <1>;

               storage_partition: partition@0 {
                   label = "storage";
                   reg = <0x0 DT_SIZE_M(16*8)>;
               };
        };
    };
};
```

When I compile and flash the firmware using this command `west build -p auto -b h743_test_board zephyr/samples/subsys/fs/littlefs && west flash` I get the following output on the console uart.

```
I: W25Q128JVPIO: SFDP v 1.5 AP ff with 1 PH
I: PH0: ff00 rev 1.5: 16 DW @ 80
I: W25Q128JVPIO: 16 MiBy flash
I: Quad read mode 4 instr [0x6b] supported
I: Quad read mode 7 instr [0xeb] supported
I: Quad read mode 7 instr [0xeb] will be used
I: QE requirement mode: 4
I: Quad mode enabled
*** Booting Zephyr OS build zephyr-v3.2.0  ***
Sample program to r/w files on littlefs
Area 4 at 0x0 on W25Q128JVPIO for 134217728 bytes
I: LittleFS version 2.4, disk version 2.0
I: FS at W25Q128JVPIO:0x0 is 32768 0x1000-byte blocks with 512 cycle
I: sizes: rd 32 ; pr 32 ; ca 2048 ; la 64
E: WEST_TOPDIR/modules/fs/littlefs/lfs.c:1077: Corrupted dir pair at {0x0, 0x1}
W: can't mount (LFS -84); formatting
W: WEST_TOPDIR/modules/fs/littlefs/lfs.c:1802: Superblock 0x0 has become unwritable
E: format failed (LFS -28)
E: fs mount error (-28)
FAIL: mount id 4 at /lfs: -28
```

It looks to me like the info messages near the top are confirming that I am able to communicate with the qspi chip but later on I get errors when attempting to mount the file system. I assume this error originates from me not setting up the partitioning correctly in the device tree overlay. Can anyone give some direction on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error some time ago with Zephyr and the stm32f723e_disco board. I was able to resolve the issue by adjusting the device-tree file based on the support I have received from the community in my github issue [55384](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/issues/55384).

The first error you receive in your log `E: WEST_TOPDIR/modules/fs/littlefs/lfs.c:1077: Corrupted dir pair at {0x0, 0x1}`, simply indicates that there is no valid littleFS initiated on your flash memory. So this should be fine, because the sample will create a file system in a later point and this message should be then gone.

However, the second error message `W: WEST_TOPDIR/modules/fs/littlefs/lfs.c:1802: Superblock 0x0 has become unwritable` indicates that you are not able to write/read properly to the flash memory. I would suggest to verify first if you are able to interact with the flash before running the littleFS sample. Please have a look at the [flash-shell](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/samples/drivers/flash_shell/README.html) sample.
The final device-tree for the flash-sample was:

```
// QSPI Flash Controller
&quadspi {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&quadspi_clk_pb2 &quadspi_bk1_ncs_pb6
                &quadspi_bk1_io0_pc9 &quadspi_bk1_io1_pc10
                &quadspi_bk1_io2_pe2 &quadspi_bk1_io3_pd13>;
    flash-id = <1>;
    status = "okay";

    mx25r512: qspi-nor-flash@0 {
        compatible = "st,stm32-qspi-nor";
        reg = <0>;
        qspi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
        size = <DT_SIZE_M(512)>; /* 64 MBytes */
        status = "okay";
        spi-bus-width = <4>;
        writeoc = "PP_1_4_4";
    };
};

// Use the QSPI driver as flash
/ {
    chosen {
        zephyr,flash-controller = &mx25r512;
    };
};
```

Additionally, verify if you have picked the proper values for:

- quadspi:

  - pinctrl (GPIO pins)
  - flash-id
- spi-nor-flash:

  - writeoc (checkout the driver doc [here](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/build/dts/api/bindings/flash_controller/st,stm32-qspi-nor.html))

I have used as a STM32Cube as reference to find the correct values. In your case this would be [STM32CubeH7](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeH7).